# Can I add a module in a package? Or how to write relative modules?

Tags: system-verilog

It's pretty common to have the exact same name for modules (such as arbiter, fifo and so on). Or when using open-source project.

- Is there a way to make a module relative?
- Can I add a module in a package?
- Is there a better way to handle that other than renaming and changing ALL the files?

**Edit:
Library and config aren't supported by Vivado.**

> Keywords marked with an asterisk (*) are
> reserved by Verilog and are not supported by Vivado synthesis.

### UG901 (v2020.1) June 24, 2020:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare modules in a package.

SystemVerilog has a way of nesting module declarations so that you can define `module A` that contains a declaration of `module B`. That makes module B private to module A, and only A can instantiate B.

For an open-source project, or any project for that matter, you can compile modules into separate libraries (`lib1`, `lib2`, etc.). Then you can have modules with the same name (`fifo`) in each library, and any module in `lib1` that instantiates a `fifo` will pick it up from the same library. If it there is no `fifo` in the same library, you can specify a library search order that instructs where to pick the `fifo`. You can even have a module with two instances of a `fifo` and have one instance come from `lib1` and the other come from `lib2`.

This is explained in section **33. Configuring the contents of a design** in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). The details of how libraries are managed is tool specific. Please read you tool's user manual or contact your tool vendor directly for support.

Comment: I've never seen any example using the libraries. That's very interesting. Thanks dave_59! I might open a new question later regarding those libraries. Hopefully that is correctly handled by Vivado.

Comment: There is a tiny example in this paper presented over 20 years ago. https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2000-HDLCon-presentation_Verilog-2000.pdf. https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2001-SNUG-paper_Verilog-2000_standard.pdf

Comment: I can't access the paper: "This website is blocked ".

Comment: The website should be publicly available. Try doing a search for the file name.

Comment: Found it using archive.org. Thanks!

Comment: How does this is handled in big companies? I don't feel it's solved using SV libraries/config features.

Comment: Big companies _do use_ libraries heavily and the `config` mechanism for finer control. The library mechanism was implemented by most tools before the Verilog 2001 standard came out. I know Vivado supports libraries.

Comment: I tried to use them without any success. Checking ug901 Synthesis user guide, it says those keywords aren't supported by Vivado. (cf my question)

Comment: I mean logical libraries, not the Verilog `library` keyword. Search ug901 for _"Vivado synthesis searches for a Verilog module with the same name as the instantiated module with a user-specified list of unified logical libraries and with a user-specified order"._ I don't know Vivado well enough to set up those logical libraries or search order. The Verilog `config` block is supposed to standardize that setup so it was no longer tool dependent.